# system.device.location without connection

Tags: location, wifi

Is it possible to use system.device.location on a windows tablet without any type of connection (wifi, 4G, etc.)?  My GeoCoordinateWatcher position location always returns IsUnknown.  However, it works when I use wifi.

Comment: … how do you expect it to locate itself if it has no data to do so?

Answer (score -1):

I believe it does.  It can use a variety of methods to get your location such as GPS, Wi-Fi triangulation, and cell phone tower triangulation ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Here is a simple example.  For some reason when you call it the first time it always returns Unknown, so I immediately call it a second time and it shows coordinates.  I hope it works for you as well.

FYI - I'd leave your Wi-Fi active on the tablet, but unplug your router or internet connection instead.

Example:

```
Public Sub GetLocationProperty()
    Dim watcher As New System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher()
    watcher.TryStart(False, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))

    Dim coord As GeoCoordinate = watcher.Position.Location

    If coord.IsUnknown <> True Then
        msgbox(coord.Latitude & " x " & coord.Longitude)
    Else
        'msgbox("Unknown latitude and longitude.")
    'Try a 2nd time
```

GetLocationProperty()
        End If 
    End Sub `

Comment: without internet GeoCoordinateWatcher can't work